# Form_for Gives Wrong Outputs After render :action=>'edit'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, form-for

I think this question might have been asked before, but I honestly don't know how to search for it.

Basically, when I do a render :action => 'edit' in the update action in controller, somehow the view outputs the form as if it's a :action => 'new' page.

form_for gave the wrong action and f.submit gave wrong button text (it gave create instead of update)

edit:

relevant parts of controller

```
def edit
  @user = User.find_by_email(current_user.email)
end

def update
  old_password=params[:user].delete(:old_password)
  @user=User.new(params[:user])

  if User.find_by_email(@user.email).valid_password?(old_password)
    logger.info 'Valid old password'
  else
    flash[:notice]='Invalid current password'
    render :action=>'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: We need some code to diagnose :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, well I actually just solved it, but it still doesnt make sense...

Comment: I know I have @user=User.new(params[:user]), but shouldn't that get overridden after render :action=>'edit'?

Comment: I think, form_for doesn't care what you are rendering. It checkes @user's `saved` flag and builds the form based on it's value.

Comment: I have a question about that, since @user = User.find_by_email(current_user.email) gets executed after render :action => 'edit', shouldn't the flag be set to "has been saved before"?

Comment: No. The `render :action` doesn't call the controller#action, it simply loads the correspoding view. Check the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, @bassneck is right - while you are rendering the edit view, the `form_for` call looks at whether the object is persisted or not (`@user.persisted?`). This has the benefit in a lot of cases of being able to use one piece of form code for both new and edit views (I'll generally have a partial `_form.html.erb` that gets used for both situations).

In your case though, it isn't leading to the desired behaviour - so wwhat you need to do is make sure you're using the relevant user object. If you want to update a user, `@user` should be the object you want to update.